# WHAT?! AM I BOTHERING YOU?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> So often forgotten, unless accidentally used,
> How am I so rotten; why am I so often abused?
>
> I'm loud and obnoxious, it's obvious when I'm there,
> For I'm not for the cautious, you might use me when you swear.
>
> Take away all restraint, and I'm what you're left with.

What am I?

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie is it ok to spoil in comments?

Comment: @Mindwin, it's better to use rot13, if you plan to spoil something. Actually, it is still debated, https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6376/using-rot13-in-comments, so it's up to you.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie it is alright, lets make an awesome Q&A

Comment: I think I spent two hours coming up with this riddle. I worked for days on my 50th puzzle, and this got more views and votes than it did... Maybe I should rethink what kind of puzzles I share.

Comment: A link from a comment in [a Meta StackOverflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372242/643383) may have inflated the views.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are:

> Caps Lock

So often forgotten, unless accidentally used,

How am I so rotten; why am I so often abused?

> People often forget they have caps lock on, or accidentally use caps lock, especially when entering passwords

I'm loud and obnoxious, it's obvious when I'm there,

For I'm not for the cautious, you might use me when you swear.

> Caps lock enable "loud" capital letters, and it's obvious when people are using it. When people are swearing, I'm sure they use caps lock

Take away all restraint, and I'm what you're left with.

> People go wild with caps lock

Additionally

> The first letter of each line spells **SHIFT**, which some people might opt for rather than caps lock

And the title...

> Is written with caps lock (or shift, who knows)

Comment: This is it! Good job!

Comment: The first two lines made me think "Internet Explorer"

Answer (score 14):

Pardon my language, but I'm going to guess

> Shit

So often forgotten, unless accidentally used,

> A piece of shit is something that's usually worthless and overlooked. You realize that something is a piece of shit when you try and use it.

How am I so rotten; why am I so often abused?

> Shit is another word for poop -- it stinks. People can kick the shit outta you.

I'm loud and obnoxious, it's obvious when I'm there,

> When people are cursing, they normally do it loudly. You could say that some people who like to sing loud and out of tune are shit singers. You can instantly hear when someone isn't a good one. Another common phrase would be, "They can't sing for shit."

For I'm not for the cautious, you might use me when you swear.

> If you don't care what others hear (like children) then you're likely to use it in your swear vocabulary

Take away all restraint, and I'm what you're left with.

> The first letter of each line spells out SHIFT, people sometimes use this in place of shit, for example: Shift happens. The F line talks about being cautious, so if you remove it (take away the restraint), you're left with SHIT.

Oh, and the title:

> There are people out there who truly annoy the shit outta you

Comment: Ha ha ha, this is great. Not the answer I was looking for, but it might fit just as well!

Comment: Whoops didn't see the actual answer posted! Thought I was on to something X)

Comment: It's no problem, this is why I don't accept answers right away, because you can get some that fit even better! +1 from me!

Answer (score 10):

Are you

> Capital letters?

So often forgotten, unless accidentally used,

> Some people do not capitalize at proper times.

How am I so rotten; why am I so often abused?

> Some times all caps means someone is yelling.

I'm loud and obnoxious, it's obvious when I'm there,

> When people talk in all caps it is seemed to be them yelling.

For I'm not for the cautious, you might use me when you swear.

> Yelling when you stub your toe?

Take away all restraint, and I'm what you're left with.

> Inside voice.

Comment: Wow, this was quick!! And further, rot13(svefg yrggref fcryy "FUVSG", juvpu vf gur xrl gung trarengrf pncvgny yrggref ba n pbzchgre)!

Comment: This isn't quite the answer I am looking for. It's so close though.

Answer (score 2):

You are

> Scream

So often forgotten, unless accidentally used

> You do use your usual voice in everyday routine, unless you hammer your finger

How am I so rotten; why am I so often abused?

> Usually people scream once they can't manage a situation regular way

For I'm not for the cautious, you might use me when you swear.

> It's hard to be cautious once you're screaming, and screamed swear is more convincing

Take away all restraint, and I'm what you're left with.

> Do not restraint yourself. Scream!