# A Riddle of Riddles

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge, acrostic

As the title states, I have decided to make another quite involved riddle, and though I should probably get away from acrostics for a while (more users are noticing them in my puzzles), I just couldn't resist this one. This is not for the faint of heart.

> If you lock your computer, when you walk away; one seems to show, with spectacular fame.
>
> A short brutal riddle, it takes quite some time; but within the answer, 'tis two you will find.
>
> One becomes two, and I'd like some pi; but first can you tell me, what am I?
>
> Hopefully these riddles, aren't bothering you; for Joe has a six, gleaming, shiny, and new.
>
> These riddles are dismembered, and each quite unique; if you solve this one, it is five that you seek.
>
> Search through this puzzle, but not in dismay; these riddles have answers, all you need are the names.

**What is the word, and how did you find it?**

**Hint**

> On your road to the answer, you may need a hint; you'll just need to search, to find each bit.

**Hint 2**:

> This one is tough, that is a fact; the acrostic you seek, is truly abstract. The answer is here, but it is there; reading and writing, of numbers beware.

**Hint 3**:

> Twinkie's got something, a fantastic start; look to the answers, they're broke into parts.

**Hint 4**:

> An answer of sorts, is what you seek; but if you think literal, your future is bleak. The acrostic is here, line by line; you just have to build it, one at a time.

---

**Side Question**: What are your thoughts on this riddle? Was it creative in your opinion? Was it too involved? Was it too easy? I would love some feedback here!

Comment: You know, you can do what I do with acrostics, if you want to continue using them, which is to add the acrostic as a more subtle hint, than a blatantly obvious one.

Comment: I've been working on some tactics for that, but this one should prove to be fun; even though it is already known to be an acrostic! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I think I have the answer, but it's also heavily based on the legwork done by @QuantumTwinkie -- go upvote their answer!

@QuantumTwinkie identified that the solutions to each line are all

> Popular Puzzle names found somewhere on this website.

If you lock your computer, when you walk away; one seems to show, with spectacular fame.

> [This one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/lock-your-computer-when-you-walk-away) has to do with fame. The solution to this puzzle is RICKROLL.

A short brutal riddle, it takes quite some time; but within the answer, 'tis two you will find.

> [This puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle) is the short brutal riddle. The solution to this puzzle is LIAR.

One in the same, I'd like some pi; but first can you tell me, what am I?

> [Maybe this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61943/a-pi-day-what-am-i), because Joe-You-Know said "Twinkies are desserts like pi. The solution to this puzzle is DOUGH.

Hopefully these riddles, aren't bothering you; for Joe has a six, gleaming, shiny, and new.

> [Maybe this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69126/what-am-i-bothering-you), where the acrostic is SHIFT. The solution to this puzzle is CAPS LOCK.

These riddles are dismembered, and each quite unique; if you solve this one, it is five that you seek.

> [This one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41846/riddled-and-dismembered), whose solution is FLOWER.

Search through this puzzle, but not in dismay; these riddles have answers, all you need are the names.

> What this means is that we have to take the numbers from the puzzle and apply it to the solutions above.

So our final solution is constructed as follows:

> The first line says that "one" is needed to show. Taking the 1st letter of the solution RICKROLL gives the letter R. 
>  The second line says it's "two" we will find. Taking the 2nd letter of the solution LIAR gives the letter I. 
>  The third line mentions "one" and "the same". The first letter of the solution DOUGH is D, and we'll need the same D again as well. 
>  The fourth line mentions that Joe has a "six". The sixth character of the solution CAPS LOCK is L. 
>  The fifth line mentions that it is "five" that we seek. The fifth letter of the solution FLOWER is E.

When we put all of the letters together, we get the acrostic word

> RIDDLE, which I'm hoping is the solution, having performed enough mental gymnastics to hopefully solve this puzzle.

Comment: Oh I didn't think of the 5th one +1 :D

Comment: Well done as always El-Guest; I thought for sure QuantumTwinkie was going to get it earlier in the day! Just hoping I didn't irritate anyone with this one as it was a back and forth type game.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I just carried on where you left off! You did an amazing job interpreting the riddle to begin with, +1 from me too! :D

Answer (score 6):

I think these are

> Popular Puzzle names

If you lock your computer, when you walk away; one seems to show, with spectacular fame.

> [This one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/lock-your-computer-when-you-walk-away)  Rickroll has to do with fame.

A short brutal riddle, it takes quite some time; but within the answer, 'tis two you will find.

> [This puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle) maybe, because it has an acrostic of LIRA, close to LIAR, the answer.

One in the same, I'd like some pi; but first can you tell me, what am I?

> [Maybe this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61943/a-pi-day-what-am-i), because Joe-You-Know said "Twinkies are desserts like pi, which may account for the "One and the same" part"

Hopefully these riddles, aren't bothering you; for Joe has a six, gleaming, shiny, and new.

> [Maybe this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69126/what-am-i-bothering-you), where the acrostic is SHIFT.

These riddles are dismembered, and each quite unique; if you solve this one, it is five that you seek.

Search through this puzzle, but not in dismay; these riddles have answers, all you need are the names.

> This could mean hidden answers like acrostics because they are present in most of the linked questions.

Comment: Look at QuantumTwinkie with some proper lateral thinking! +1

Comment: I wondered if I actually had something to do with the puzzle, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You should definitely read the Making Of for this one once I post it! :)

Comment: The pi one could be referring to you, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61943/a-pi-day-what-am-i

Comment: hahah that would be funny :D

Comment: I think it makes sense, because rot13(Gjvaxvrf ner qrffregf yvxr cv, juvpu znl nppbhag sbe gur "Bar naq gur fnzr" cneg)

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think of that thanks :D

Comment: Rot13(Npghnyyl zrnag gb or "bar orpbzrf gjb", ohg terng svaq!)

Comment: I think the last one has to do with this one, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41846/riddled-and-dismembered

Answer (score 4):

### **The Making Of:** ***A Riddle of Riddles***

---

***Note:*** *This is not a solution to the puzzle, but provides notes from its poser. This type of answer has been [approved by the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/sharing-and-rewarding-what-went-into-making-a-good-puzzle).*

***Caution:*** *This post may contain spoilers.*

---

### ***Inspiration***

The inspiration for this puzzle was simple; I was talking to a colleague about a new idea for a nested riddle. Out of the blue, the title *A Riddle of Riddles in Riddles from Riddles* came to be. Now though this was amusing, I decided it was a bit over the top and simplified it. I've enjoyed quite a few riddles here and the ones involved in this riddle are just a few of my favorites. I decided to give my respect to these riddles, and write a riddle of riddles.

### ***Creative Steps***

I originally planned on a riddle in which the first letter of the accepted answer for each would spell out the answer to this riddle (in the true nature of an acrostic); however, this was difficult to do, even looking to other riddles by some of my favorite writers. Thus the numerical system came to be; I took inspiration from my own riddle [*Hunting Season is Open*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69686/hunting-season-is-open) in which the final answer was spelled out from each riddle prior by giving numerical placements. I was then able to use my favorite riddles by specifying the placement of the letters. To remain true to the acrostic nature of the riddle, I decided to place the chosen riddles in such a way that each letter returned would spell the answer in order.

### ***Logistical Steps and Resources***

The riddles here on Puzzling.SE were my resources. Some of my favorite writers here are:

- Hugh Meyers - [*Riddled and Dismembered*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41846/riddled-and-dismembered)
- QuantumTwinkie - [*A Pi Day What Am I?*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61943/a-pi-day-what-am-i)
- Joe-You-Know - [*What? Am I Bothering You?*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69126/what-am-i-bothering-you)
- Roland - [*A short, brutal riddle.*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle)
- Khale_Kitha - [*Lock your computer when you walk away!*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/lock-your-computer-when-you-walk-away)

### ***Final Thoughts***

This riddle was incredibly fun to write, even more fun to adapt. I think my favorite thing about it is that not only does it pay homage to the original riddles and their writers, it also made a few of them laugh.

Answer (score 3):

Well for the acrostic, this is what I have so far

> If you unscramble it, it may say, IS OATH

Comment: Good attempt, but the acrostic is not obvious here; you'll have to search for it! ;)